# Connection String in Class Library Web Config file in C#

Tags: c#, string, class, connection

I have assigned a number of connection strings in the web config file for my class library.

I decided to change one of the databases in the  tag, but when the library is built and add to the reference of my project it still refers back to the old table.

I have tried cleaning both the project and the class library and rebuilding the class library.

Also, I have removed the reference and re-added it to the project, but it still insists on calling the old table in the  tag.

Does anyone know what is causing this or know of a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.config file that is used is the one pertaining to the ASP.NET (Core) application and not the class library. Edit the one in your website's web.config and the changes will be reflected.

Comment: Thank you...Did later work it out. :). So I assume you can use the WebConfig file in the class library? :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you're happy with my answer please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: No, the class library will inherit the web.config of the web application referencing it, or the app.config of the console/webforms/wpf/web service application referencing it. Do NOT create a web.config inside a class library.